# How to add class to the clicked button and remove a class to the previously clicked button in React

Tags: jquery, reactjs, class, button, addition

I have a list of buttons (this list can become larger by adding entries or smaller by deleting them) on the left side of the website and when I click on a button I want to show content stored in the particular button on the right side of the website.

For now, I was able to add an active class to the buttons. So when I click on a button its content will be shown. But I want to only show one content at a time without clicking the same button again to remove the class. Like, when I click on another button, the class of the previous one clicked will be removed and added to the actual clicked one. How can this be approached?

Also, I want the content shown in the same place. Now, the content starts at the height of the related button. I do not want to use a framework. I found several examples but every one contained hardcoded buttons/contents.

Thank you for your answers.

Here is the component of the button:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Entrie from "./Entrie";

const EntrieButton = ({ entrie, handleEditClick, handleDeleteClick }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  const handleSetActive = (e) => {
    setActive(!active);
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-full bg-blue-300">
      <button
        key={entrie.id}
        className="my-2 ml-2 rounded-sm shadow-sm overflow-hidden w-1/4"
        onClick={handleSetActive}
      >
        <div className="flex justify-between w-full overflow-hidden">
          <p className="bg-purple-300 w-1/4 px-2 py-4">{entrie.date}</p>
          <p className="bg-yellow-300 w-3/4 px-2 py-4">{entrie.heading}</p>
        </div>
      </button>
      <Entrie
        entrie={entrie}
        onEditClick={handleEditClick}
        onDeleteClick={handleDeleteClick}
        active={active}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default EntrieButton;
```

in case you need the component of the Entrie with stored content:

```
import React from "react";

const Entrie = ({ entrie, onEditClick, onDeleteClick, active }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={`container w-2/3 bg-white float-right h-full px-14 py-2 mt-2 mr-2" ${
        active ? "block" : "hidden"
      }`}
    >
      <p className="">{entrie.date}</p>
      <h2 className="text-2xl">{entrie.heading}</h2>
      <p>{entrie.mood}</p>
      <p>{entrie.text}</p>
      <div className="w-full flex justify-around py-8 border-t-2">
        <button onClick={() => onEditClick(entrie)} className="">
          <abbr title="Edit">
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              viewBox="0 0 20 20"
              width="20px"
            >
              <path d="M12.3 3.7l4 4L4 20H0v-4L12.3 3.7zm1.4-1.4L16 0l4 4-2.3 2.3-4-4z" />
            </svg>
          </abbr>
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => onDeleteClick(entrie.id)} className="">
          <abbr title="Delete">
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              viewBox="0 0 20 20"
              width="20px"
            >
              <path d="M6 2l2-2h4l2 2h4v2H2V2h4zM3 6h14l-1 14H4L3 6zm5 2v10h1V8H8zm3 0v10h1V8h-1z" />
            </svg>
          </abbr>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Entrie;
```

Here is the component where I render the buttons with map function

```
import React from "react";
import EntrieButton from "./EntrieButton";

const EntrieList = ({ entries, handleEditClick, handleDeleteClick }) => {
  const entrieCount = entries.length;

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2>
        You have {entrieCount} {entrieCount === 1 ? `entrie` : `entries`} so
        far.
      </h2>
      <div className="h-screen overflow-auto bg-gray-100 mb-6 w-full">
        {entries.map((entrie) => (
          <EntrieButton
            key={entrie.id}
            entrie={entrie}
            handleEditClick={handleEditClick}
            handleDeleteClick={handleDeleteClick}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EntrieList;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question I assume that there will an array of buttons and associated contents as follows and using `map()` function you are rendering the list of buttons.

```
[{button: btn1, content: content1}, {button: btn2, content: content2}]
```

In this array you can include an extra parameter like `isActive: true/false` and update this array using a function and pass that function reference to the child component and call it on button click.

Comment: I updated the question above so you can see how I use the map function. I understand your suggestion when having fixed buttons but idk how to get there when buttons are not hardcoded.